# importing static javascript functions into scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

In a third party library react-native-fbsdk-next I have a file FBAccessToken.ts
The class below has a few ordinary members and a static member function.

```
class FBAccessToken {

  accessToken: string;
  permissions: Array<string>;

  static getCurrentAccessToken() {
    return new Promise<FBAccessToken | null>((resolve) => {
    ...
    }
  }
}

export default FBAccessToken;
```

I need to import both the class members as well as the static function.

My strategy is to use a scala class and a companion object like so

```
  @native
  @JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", "FBAccessToken")
  class FBAccessToken extends js.Object {
    def accessToken: String = native
    def permissions: Array[String] = native
  }

  @native
  @JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", "FBAccessToken")
  object FBAccessToken extends js.Object {
    def getCurrentAccessToken: Promise[FBAccessToken | Null] = native
  }
```

But the static function to companion object import seems to not work.
`sbt fastOptJs` works but on running the app in a simulator I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[4], "react-native-fbsdk-next").FBAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`FBAccessToken` is exported under the `default` export in the JavaScript library:

```js
export default FBAccessToken;
```

and not under its own name `"FBAccessToken"`.

Therefore, when importing it from Scala.js, you have to use `JSImport.Default` as the second argument ot `@JSImport`:

```scala
@JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", JSImport.Default)
```

This applies both to the `class` and to the `object`

Comment: After doing the above the, it fails again on the static function import when it is called.
See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646551/async-function-called-in-a-slinky-scalajs-setup-causes-render-to-fail