# Async function called in a slinky/scalajs setup causes render to fail

Tags: scala.js

I'm unsure if this is a question for the general scala.js world or specifically slinky/slinky-native/slinky-hot

FYI, using

```
libraryDependencies += "me.shadaj" %%% "slinky-native" % "0.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "me.shadaj" %%% "slinky-hot" % "0.7.0"

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.10.1")
```

I have an async function that returns login status with facebook

```
object LoginController {
    def userFBLoginStatus: Future[LoginStatus] = {
      FBAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken.toFuture.map {
```

This internally calls a `static` function import from a javascript library

```
  @native
  @JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", JSImport.Default)
  object FBAccessToken extends js.Object {
    def getCurrentAccessToken: Promise[FBAccessToken | Null] = native
  }
```

I call it in the main App component like so

```
@react class App extends Component {
  type Props = Unit
  type State = Boolean

  def initialState = false


  override def componentDidMount(): Unit = {
    LoginController.userFBLoginStatus.map {
      case LoggedIn => setState(true)
      case LoggedOut => setState(false)
    }
  }

  override def render(): ReactElement = {
    if (state)
      View(//welcome view)
    else
      View(//login page view)
```

The intention being that the view should change based on the output of the async function called in `componentDidMount`
`sbt clean fastOptJS` works fine but on rendering the app fails with

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this$.then')
This error is located at:
    in App$ (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in DanceApp(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this$.then')
```

If I comment out the async call in `componentDidMount`, the rendering works fine. See the `(evaluating 'this$.then')`, looks like its looking for a Promise.then?

Equivalent react code works e.g. where `fetchWells()` returns a javascript `Promise`

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { wells: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchWells()
      .then(res => this.setState({ wells: res.wells }) )
  }

  render () {
    const { wells } = this.state
    return wells.length ? this.renderWells() : (
      <span>Loading wells...</span>
    )
  }
}
```

UPDATE: following the answer changing it to works!

```
  @native
  @JSImport("react-native-fbsdk-next", "AccessToken")
  object FBAccessToken extends js.Object {
    def getCurrentAccessToken(): Promise[FBAccessToken | Null] = native
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see [in the documentation here](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next#login-button--access-token), `getCurrentAccessToken` is a *function* returning a `Promise`, so it needs to be declared with `()`:

```scala
def getCurrentAccessToken(): Promise[FBAccessToken | Null] = native
```

It's also worth double-checking the import path, since that documentation suggests that it's inside a top-level object called `AccessToken`, and not as the `default` export.